# Getting Error (Code: 105, Version: 1.17.2) with parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to save data into my database with `Parse` but every time I run the code getting following error

> [Error]: Invalid field name:  name. (Code: 105, Version: 1.17.2)

I have tried removing spaces from the name still the error show's up

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let person = PFObject(className: "People")
       person.add("dee", forKey: "name")
       person.add("odus", forKey: "last_name")
       person.add(36, forKey: "age")

       person.saveInBackground()
   }
```

I expected it to be saved in my database

Comment: And how is People defined?

Comment: people basically is a table in dashboard i am generating a new table  from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried @Davi Macêdo's code with XCode 10.3 and Parse 1.17.2 installed manually. 
Had to include these Framworks:

```
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.1.1.3.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

And it worked.

When trying the .add approach, I got this message on Autocomplete about the .add method:

`Adds an object to the end of the array associated with a given key`

I wasn't able to save it to an existing Person class, but was able to save it as an Array in a new class I called Test

So, it seems @Davi Macêdo's code is correct and you are misusing the .add method.
It worked on my Test class because it didn't have any columns yet, so it created a name property as an Array, an age property as an Array and a last_name property as another Array.
Yours probably didn't work because you already have some data in there as a String.

Please check that.

Comment: I am using .add in the xcode now the reason was before i set the array name as key and i was trying to re enter it.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let person = PFObject(className: "People")
       person["name"] = "dee"
       person["last_name"] = "odus"
       person["age"] = 36

       person.saveInBackground()
   }
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#saving-objects

Comment: yup i tried doesn't work now it has been replaced with .add

Comment: Where did you see this information that it was replaced? Take a look in the docs [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#saving-objects). It is exactly in the way I showed you. What's the error that you have when running my code?